# OroCommerce Community Edition with Demo Data setup on AWS server but php commands not working

Tags: orocommerce, orocrm

We have setup aws server with OroCommerce Community Edition with Demo Data to work with OroCommerce Community Edition but we are facing challenges with php commands not running on the terminal. It shows error like:

> -bash: php:command not found

same issue with the composer as well.

We have tried many commands on the terminal relatex to OroCommerce cache flush/clean or even to set website into the dev mode but commands not working. here are the commands:

```
-bash: php:command not found
-bash: composer:command not found
```

Answer (score 1):

This is probably because the application is installed in docker.
Try to get a list of instances:

```
docker ps -a
```

Comment: I am a newbee in OroCommerce, so please provide me the solution why I am not able to run any PHP command like: php bin/console oro:assets:install --env=prod